# Marklogic large delete

Tags: marklogic

I want to know if anyone has experience of deleting millions of documents in Marklogic?
At the moment I used the simple xqueries to fetch the document uri s which need to be deleted and then I use corb to batch the whole operation.

Is there a faster way to delete millions of documents once I have a list of Uris ?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to tackle this. The first question is how you retrieve the document uri's? Best approach for that is using the URI lexicon, and `cts:uris` or `cts:uri-match`. Second is how you perform the delete. You could iterate over the found uri's, and call `xdmp:document-delete` for each, but you might consider skipping all above, and revert to `xdmp:collection-delete` alltogether. That seems to work very efficient. It does require you to have a unique collection label assigned, and it can be delete entirely..

HTH!

Comment: I dont think xdmp:collection-delete will help in my case, as I have a collection "/a/b/c" which contains 2 million docs and only lets say 1 million are eligible. So, if I use xdmp:collection-delete, it will delete all documents..On your question about, how I get the URI's, I am using cts:uris.

Answer (score 3):

Calling [`xdmp:spawn`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn) or [`xdmp:spawn-function`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn-function) might be a little faster than corb, simply because it avoids a network round-trip.

If the documents are organized for it, `xdmp:collection-delete` or `xdmp:directory-delete` could also be faster. But the collections or directories should be around 1,000-100,000 documents each, ideally.

Finally if you want to get rid of everything, it would be much faster to clear the forest or the database. It could even be faster to export the stuff you want to keep (using XQSync perhaps), clear the database, and then re-import.

Comment: Thats the thing, the documents I want to delete are not organized. I will try the xdmp:spawn now and see how it fair's against corb.

Answer (score 1):

Note also that if you have directory creation enabled that deletes are vastly slower.
If you do not need direcgtories (only really needed for WEBDAV) I suggest not using directories then deletes will be much faster.